# считывание из блокнота нескольких данных

Tags: c

Нужно, чтобы из блокнота считывались несколько значений X и Y.
Пример блокнота:

```
12 96
84 5
546 7
...
```

Нужно, чтобы считывались значения и производилась над ними операция, скажем, умножение. Открывать блокнот я уже научился и считывать данные, но вот как сделать максимально просто, чтобы программа считывала именно два разных числа из каждой строки?

Comment: Под блокнотом Вы подразумеваете файл с расширением .txt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while (!feof(stream)) // пока не дошли до конца
{ 
    fscanf_s(stream, "%d%d", &x, &y); 
    // z = x * y;  
}
```

где `stream` - объект типа `FILE*`, а `x, y` - переменные необходимого Вам числового типа.

При необходимости, можете добавить дополнительные проверки ввода, или же, если известно количество строк в файле - то сделать цикл типа `for`.